# How to remove stream video in next scene AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a project with a video in a scene, but when I go to the next scene the video keeps appearing.  How can I remove it.

My code so far is:

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var videoConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
videoConnection.connect(null);
var videoStream:NetStream = new NetStream(videoConnection);
videoStream.play("short_jump.flv");
var metaListener:Object = new Object();
metaListener.onMetaData = onMetaData;
videoStream.client = metaListener;
var video:Video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(videoStream);
stage.addChild(video);
video.x=200;

function onMetaData(data:Object):void
{
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMovie);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMovie);
}

function playMovie(event:MouseEvent):void
{
videoStream.play("short_jump.flv");
}

function stopMovie(event:MouseEvent):void
{
videoStream.pause();
}
```

---

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

video.attachCamera( null ) stops audio and video but the last frame remains in the video. you should just video.visible = false afterwards so you don't see that frame. there's a bug where clear() doesn't do what it should.